# How to call struct method from a spawned thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

I am new to multithreaded programming and I am unable to execute following code:

```
use std::thread;

struct Test;

impl Test {
    pub fn foo(&self) {
        for i in 0..5 {
            thread::spawn(|| { self.bar(); });
        }
    }
    
    pub fn bar(&self) {
        println!("bar");
    }
}


fn main() {
    let t = Test{};
    t.foo()
}
```

I receive following error:

> `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a
> `'static` lifetime requirement

I am assuming this happens because thread does not know if the object `self` refers to does not get deleted during the execution of the thread. Is there any way to somehow execute this code? Or do I need my methods to have static lifetimes? (if such thing is even possible)

Here is the [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c1a3cfbc96eaeba6b73c6ce99878011).

Comment: [Here's an example using `crossbeam` to solve your problem, as suggested in the linked question.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0aa2430b6db6afd95ffbacc54ccb4936) If this does not answer your question, please [edit] it to explain how it's different. Thanks!

Comment: @trentcl Would it be possible to do something similar with only `std` ?

Comment: Not safely, no, because standard threads can outlive their parent, as the other question's answer also mentions. You can fix some similar problems [using `Arc`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=02b44c43daf78db4709cfc9b1fbb526a) but in this case it does not have the same (or deterministic) output, precisely because the spawned threads are not joined before the main thread ends.